# BASH Variable to string comparison always fails

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, scripting

I've searched, and searched, and searched... but I just can't figure out why on earth this simple BASH function is failing.

The code:

```
# Function to quickly disable or enable proxy server, system wide
    proxee() {
        MODE=$(gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy mode)
        echo $MODE

        if [ "$MODE" = "manual" ]
        then
            gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
            echo "Proxy Disabled"

        elif [ "$MODE" = "none" ]
        then
            gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
            echo "Proxy Enabled"
        else
           echo "FAIL"
        fi
    }
```

Every time I try to run it I get the following output:

```
'none'
FAIL
```

I essentially just want to compare the variable I have declared with a string literal.

I am pretty new to bash scripting and I've read over 15 different answers from Stack Overflow (this seems to be a common problem) - but I just can't figure it out!

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy mode` returns `'none'` including the quote signs (`'`).

Therefore you have to include them into the comparison:

```
...
elif [ "$MODE" = "'none'" ]
then
...
```

Comment: Wow. The simplest of things... I am an idiot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

just change this line:

```
elif [ "$MODE" = "'none'" ]
```

string returned to mode is 'none' not none
Enjoy

Comment: Thanks Vairis. Upvoted your answer, had to give it to bmk just because he was slightly faster. Cheers